# Intellij IDEA, how to revert operation "Remember, don't ask again"?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I add a file in IntelliJ IDEA, it shows me a dialog 'Add File to Git', and I choose 'remember, don't ask again' by mistake. Now I want the dialog to show again. What can I do to revert this operation besides reset settings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try changing the following option:

Preferences > Version control > Confirmation > When files are created > Add silently.

Comment: I went to File -> New Projects Setup -> Preferences for New Projects, and changed it for good! This has always driven me nuts!